# Open Bootstrap Modal in a Servlet

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, servlets, bootstrap-modal

This is what I currently have now:

```
<a href="../../modal/add-training-program.jsp" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#modal" data-keyboard="false">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus-sign"></span>
            Add</a>
```

This opens up a bootstrap modal with the form for adding a training program.
I'd like to reuse this for editing a training program but I want the form fields to be initialized with their value in the database.

Is there a way to call the servlet first (to do the processing of the records from the database), and that servlet will be the one to load the modal?

If it's not possible, can you recommend a way to achieve this?

Comment: @jlucky on click make a ajax call to servlet and return json from servlet and set that value using jquery.val and then open bootstrap modal using jquery `$('#myModal').modal('show');` u will get prepopulated values.

Comment: @pise I'm not quite familiar with ajax and json. Can you provide some sample codes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here is the code for ajax call**

Give a id to your a href and on click below function will be called in which ajax call is made to servlet

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#modalData").click(function(){

var request = ({"message":'Hello from browser'});
var jsonobj=JSON.stringify(request);
$.ajax({
    data: {para:jsonobj},
    dataType: 'json',
    url: './TestServlet',
    type: 'POST',
    success: function(jsonObj){
        // set value in input text of modal form
        (#address).val(jsonObj.address);  
    // open modal
        $('#myModal').modal('show');  
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Ajax readyState: '+xhr.readyState+'\nstatus: '+xhr.status + ' ' + err);
    }
});

// on hidden reset bootstrap modal

// on close or hidden modal value will be reset
   $('#myModal').on('hide.bs.modal', function () {

      $(this).find('form')[0].reset();
   })

 });

 </script>
```

**Servlet code return json data**

```
    request.setCharacterEncoding("utf8");
    response.setContentType("application/json");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    // below code to parse json receive from ajax call
    JSONObject jsonObj = (JSONObject) JSONValue.parse(request.getParameter("para"));
    System.out.println(jsonObj.get("message"));
    JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
    obj.put("address", "address of the users");
    out.print(obj);
```